# Can't Disable site feature from powerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

im getting this error when i try to Disable site feature ExpirationWorkflow .

Feature 'c85e5759-f323-4efb-b548-443d2216efb5' is not active ated at this scope. At line:1 char:18

when i try to enable it's give me feature is alrady enable for site ??

Comment: Have u checked it from Site that it is not actiavted ?

Answer (score 2):

seems its a issue with Sp migration 2007 to 2010 ?? 
and it's can be fix doing below steps .

1.open the site collection in SharePoint Designer 2010, in the Navigation section, click on All Files, then click on _catalogs.

2.Check whether there’s wfpub list or folder. If it is a folder, delete it,

3.then run the below PowerShell commands:
$site = Get-SPSite

Disable-SPFeature -Url $site.URL -Identity Workflows -Confirm:$false

Disable-SPFeature -Url $site.URL -Identity OffWFCommon -Confirm:$false

Enable-SPFeature -Url $site.URL -Identity OffWFCommon

Enable-SPFeature -Url $site.URL -Identity Workflows

working all good for my site collection 
cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Use Force parameter like this:

Enable-SPFeature –identity "c85e5759-f323-4efb-b548-443d2216efb5" -URL `http://somesite` -Force

Comment: He is trying to disable a Site Feature, and you are giving Powershell command to Enable a feature! :/

Comment: Read the post carefully...he also questioned..when i try to enable it's give me feature is alrady enable for site ??
So i answered this part.

Comment: Read my comment above..as well

Comment: So you are saying that your answer isn't complete? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeap...Whatever I was able to help I did...

Comment: hey guys seems its issue with 2007 2010 migration